# How to disable autocomplete and autofill for chrome / jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome, autocomplete

I want to disable both Chrome autocomplete AND Chrome autofill.

I'm using **JQuery UI** to autocomplete an input field. My **jquery-ui autocomplete** works fine, however chrome browser displays it's own *autofill* on top of mine making it difficult for users to select the correct dropdown item.

I'm using `autocomplete="off"` which seems to disable autocomplete for chrome but shows *autofill options*.

I've tried the following:

- `autocomplete="chrome-off"` `autocomplete="false"` `autocomplete="disabled"`

Those attribute values ( or any invalid attribute values ) seem to be disabling the *autofill but do enable *autocomplete*.

**Important:**
I cannot use random name attributes since I am performing ajax requests for my own jquery-ui autocomplete

Comment: If you have not referred this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill, you can check if this answers your need

Comment: @NewBee Though these two questions are quite similar, none of the answers on that one actually work on my case. Last update was for September: 2020 but even that does not work for me, as mentioned on my original query.

Answer (score 3):

> autocomplete="off"

doesn't work anymore. The only thing which works from 2019 is

> autocomplete="new-password"

Comment: As per my original post, I've already tried this. This is equivalent to passing a random value. It disables autofill but does show a chrome autocomplete dropdown.

Comment: https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Disable-Chrome-Autofill-Autocomplete-jQuery.html check this jquery plugin and let me know

Comment: Thank you for your comment. As I mentioned on my original post 'I cannot use random name attributes since I am performing ajax requests for my own jquery-ui autocomplete'

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution by combining a few different answers.

**STEP 1**

In order to fix the **autocomplete** issue, you can add a dummy invisible input field as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag?page=3&tab=votes).
So your html should look something like this:

```
<input id="dummy_location" type="search" name="dummy_location" style='display: none;'>
<input id="location" type="search" name="location">
```

This will cause chrome autofill pop-up

**STEP 2**

To disable the autofill pop-up, we need to add an invalid value for the *autocomplete* attribute like this.

```
$("#fromcity_ac").attr({
     autocomplete: "chrome-off",
});
```

**YOU CAN STOP HERE**.

Chrome will work fine, however, autocomplete issue will pop up on other browsers such as firefox. To fix this you can edit **step 2** by checking what browser is being used and setting an appropriate value for the autocomplete attribute.

```js
var isChromium = window.chrome;
var winNav = window.navigator;
var vendorName = winNav.vendor;
var isOpera = typeof window.opr !== "undefined";
var isIEedge = winNav.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") > -1;
var isIOSChrome = winNav.userAgent.match("CriOS");

// Autocomplete default value
var autocomplete = "chrome-off";
if (isIOSChrome) {
  // is Google Chrome on IOS
} else if (
  isChromium !== null &&
  typeof isChromium !== "undefined" &&
  vendorName === "Google Inc." &&
  isOpera === false &&
  isIEedge === false
) {
  // Is google chrome
} else {
  // Is firefox
  autocomplete = "off";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of early 2022 this seems to work:

```
autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autofocus="" role="combobox" spellcheck="false"
```

It is the technique used on the google home page search box.

Comment: Confirmed, for a thing that's a combobox the role="combobox" _does_ seem to be the thing that works at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

`autocomplete="off"` to `autocomplete="random-value"`. This is the temporary fix for now.

Comment: As per my original post, I've already tried this. This is equivalent to `autocomplete="disabled"` whitch is invalid. It disables autofill but does show a chrome autocomplete dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

try this , this works for chrome

```
autocomplete="chrome-off"
```

Comment: As per my original post, I've already tried this. It disables autofill but does show a chrome autocomplete dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Try autocomplete="off" in your input field and also use JavaScript to set the attribute dynamically. Chrome sometimes respects the dynamic change over static HTML.

```
<input type="text" id="yourInput" autocomplete="off">
<script>
  document.getElementById('yourInput').autocomplete = 'chrome-off';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome automatically find the input fields and override the autocomplete behavior's. So we need to put random string to all input field when focus.

First set `autocomplete="off"` to all input fields and remove autofocus of any input field (if any).

Then put below scripts section on your html page or layout.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {

                function generateRandomString() {
                    var alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
                    var randomString = '';

                    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                        var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length);
                        randomString += alphabet.charAt(randomIndex);
                    }

                    return randomString;
                }


           
//this focus event listener randomly change the autocomplete of focused input 
                $('input').focus(function (e) {
                    $(this).attr('autocomplete', generateRandomString())                
                });


            });

</script>
```

gist link: https://gist.github.com/Alagappapandian/f4f9f374e8cc2767bb754e73d4854443